# deserialize data from nested JSON using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, json-deserialization

I have time series data in nested Json which I am struggling to get into a flattened dataframe.

## Input Data

Data is here: https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/historical

## Expected Output

A flat Pandas dataframe:   country|date|cases|deaths|recovered

## What I have Tried

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/historical', headers)
json_data = r.json()
```

Now, I can `df = pd.json_normalize(json_data, max_level=1)` but that leaves me with embedded lists.
I can also `df = pd.json_normalize(json_data)` but that just creates a new column for every single date which is not sustainable as time progresses.

There must be an elegant way of doing this. The last resort would be writing a Python loop.

Comment: Share a sample of the json data in ur question so someone can work with and provide a possible solution

Comment: _There must be an elegant way of doing this. The last resort would be writing a Python loop._ I think the most "elegant" way might be the loop.

Comment: @sammywemmy  The raw json URL is the question! Not only have I provided the raw json, I've provided code to download it.

Comment: u shared an entire data. what u should do is share a sample, not the entire data. u've downloaded the data, cut a small part of it that represents what u want to achieve and share that in ur question.

Comment: dont get me wrong. it is cool u shared d data u did. it just is easier for whoever wants to answer ur question to deal with a subset of it, and allow u extrapolate whatever answer to the entire dataset

Answer (score 1):

this is a subset of your data, for the country of Afghanistan(the first entry in the json data):

```
content = [{"country":"Afghanistan","province":None,"timeline":{"cases":{"3/13/20":7,"3/14/20":11,"3/15/20":16,"3/16/20":21,"3/17/20":22,"3/18/20":22,"3/19/20":22,"3/20/20":24,"3/21/20":24,"3/22/20":40,"3/23/20":40,"3/24/20":74,"3/25/20":84,"3/26/20":94,"3/27/20":110,"3/28/20":110,"3/29/20":120,"3/30/20":170,"3/31/20":174,"4/1/20":237,"4/2/20":273,"4/3/20":281,"4/4/20":299,"4/5/20":349,"4/6/20":367,"4/7/20":423,"4/8/20":444,"4/9/20":484,"4/10/20":521,"4/11/20":555},"deaths":{"3/13/20":0,"3/14/20":0,"3/15/20":0,"3/16/20":0,"3/17/20":0,"3/18/20":0,"3/19/20":0,"3/20/20":0,"3/21/20":0,"3/22/20":1,"3/23/20":1,"3/24/20":1,"3/25/20":2,"3/26/20":4,"3/27/20":4,"3/28/20":4,"3/29/20":4,"3/30/20":4,"3/31/20":4,"4/1/20":4,"4/2/20":6,"4/3/20":6,"4/4/20":7,"4/5/20":7,"4/6/20":11,"4/7/20":14,"4/8/20":14,"4/9/20":15,"4/10/20":15,"4/11/20":18},"recovered":{"3/13/20":0,"3/14/20":0,"3/15/20":0,"3/16/20":1,"3/17/20":1,"3/18/20":1,"3/19/20":1,"3/20/20":1,"3/21/20":1,"3/22/20":1,"3/23/20":1,"3/24/20":1,"3/25/20":2,"3/26/20":2,"3/27/20":2,"3/28/20":2,"3/29/20":2,"3/30/20":2,"3/31/20":5,"4/1/20":5,"4/2/20":10,"4/3/20":10,"4/4/20":10,"4/5/20":15,"4/6/20":18,"4/7/20":18,"4/8/20":29,"4/9/20":32,"4/10/20":32,"4/11/20":32}}}]
```

One approach would be to read in the timeline data, and then [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the country and provinces data to the dataframe:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(content[0]['timeline']).assign(country = content[0]['country'],
                                                  province = content[0]['province']
                                                  )

res.head()


         cases    deaths    recovered   country    province
3/13/20   7          0        0        Afghanistan  None
3/14/20   11         0        0        Afghanistan  None
3/15/20   16         0        0        Afghanistan  None
3/16/20   21         0        1        Afghanistan  None
3/17/20   22         0        1        Afghanistan  None
```

Note that the entire data is wrapped in a list, hence the 0 index.

Comment: This is useful +1 upvote. But I still don't have a solution to my problem. How does one apply this intermediate step to deliver the final dataframe?

Comment: ur entire json is wrapped in a list, so if u apply this particular code to it, where content represents the entire json, u should have ur dataframe. it will be quite a lot, and hopefully, should fit into memory. scratch that, it should fit into memory

Comment: This does it.`results = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(json_data)):
 df = pd.DataFrame(json_data[i]['timeline']).assign(country = json_data[i]['country'], province = json_data[i]['province'])
 results = results.append(df, ignore_index=False)`